# HTTP response code checker in VB?

Tags: vb.net, http, networking, response

i'm a new in VB and i'm trying to make a program that
gets and displays the HTTP response code of a website.

something like:

http response code of target website www.example.com : 200 OK

etc.

I Tried to code it myself but i couldn't , And i also tried to find online but i didn't
found something that works.

i found this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.statuscode(v=vs.110).aspx

i tried that and that didn't really helped me.

Anyone has a code that does that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a C# guy, so this might not be perfect, but I believe this should do it.

```
Public Shared Function GetResponse(uri As String) As HttpStatusCode
    Dim req As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(uri)
    Dim resp As HttpWebResponse
    Try
        resp = DirectCast(req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Catch ex As WebException
        resp = DirectCast(ex.Response, HttpWebResponse)
    End Try

    Return resp.StatusCode
End Function
```